# Perl for Windows GUI

Tags: windows, perl, user-interface

I searched the internet before coming here. I guess everyone's needs are different. I want a Windows GUI program that will get information from database and show it in grid and have a delete button next to each record. I also want it to have a link, for example if the id number of the record is clicked, it opens new browser and navigates to a page associated with it, and completes forms then submits by itself.

The question is: Since there are many modules out there, which one is the best for this?

(Perl Nubie)

Comment: Why not use some kind of database explorer? What database do you want to query?

Comment: It's MySQL. The point is that you want to cilck on a row and open a new Win32::Ole browser application and "drive" it through Perl

Comment: I still do not see an advantage over for example [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/index.html)

Comment: Do you own the website that you are interacting with? If so this seems like a very strange workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can truly say what is BEST, but the option of the   `Tk`  module with a backend of, in your case, `DBD::MySQL`, is maybe the most "standard" for things like this in Perl. Examples for both can be found all around online.

Here are some for SQL with mySQL and DBD :

http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/Perl-DBI-examples.html

Here is a good document of examples for perl TK:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-perltkmodule/index.html

As far as opening a browser - a simple system command will do:

```
my @command = ('start', $url);
system(@command);
```

^That is for Windows. It looks like you have a decently large application you want to build - opening a browser is just a small part of it - you will want to execute the above when a button is pressed, no doubt.

The last part...submitting data to forms on the web, is a topic called "web crawling"...  `WWW::Mechanize`  is a library to look into - Google "perl web crawler" and you are bound to get more good examples.

I found this with a  little searching - it looks to be of use to you:

http://www.stratos.me/2009/05/writing-a-simple-web-crawler-in-perl/

Comment: How would you then drive the browser, lets say fill out the forms from program then submit to a page

Comment: Edited my answer to address it!

Comment: My current program does it in Dos, and I want it to be built in Windows GUI. The application is not that big, probably will hold no more than 2000 rows. The part I worry about is when I open a browser, will I be able to control it with Win32::Ole?

Comment: I sure @PinkElephantsOnParade meant that your program's code is going to be big. Developing a GUI app takes a lot of code.

Answer (score 3):

Give one (nasty) precondition, ca. 25 lines of HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <hta:application id="demo" scroll="No"></hta>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script language = "PerlScript"
          src      = "demo.pl"
          type     = "text/perlscript"
  ></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="DoOnLoad()" onunload="DoOnUnLoad()">
  <object classid = "clsid:67397AA3-7FB1-11D0-B148-00A0C922E820"
          id      = "id_oDC"
          style   = "position:relative;width:1px;height:1px"
  ></object>
  <object classid = "clsid:CDE57A43-8B86-11D0-B3C6-00A0C90AEA82"
          id      = "id_oDG"
          style   = "position:relative;width:100%;height:95%"
  ></object>
 </body>
</html>
```

and ca. 40 lines of Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE qw( in );
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects';
use vars qw( $window );

my $oAdoDC;
my $oAdoDG;

sub DoOnLoad {
  my $owda                    = $window->document->all;
  $oAdoDC                     = $owda->id_oDC;
  $oAdoDC->{ConnectionString} = 'DSN=SakilaGent';
  $oAdoDG                     = $owda->id_oDG;
  $oAdoDC->{CursorType}       = adOpenKeyset;
  $oAdoDG->Font->{Name}       = "Arial";
  $oAdoDG->Font->{Size}       = "8";
  $oAdoDG->HeadFont->{Name}   = "Arial";
  $oAdoDG->HeadFont->{Size}   = "8";
  $oAdoDC->{RecordSource}     = "select * from customer";
  $oAdoDG->{Caption}          = $oAdoDC->{RecordSource};
  $oAdoDC->Refresh();
  $oAdoDG->{DataSource}       = $oAdoDC;
}

sub DoOnUnLoad {
  $oAdoDG->{ DataSource }->Close();
  $oAdoDC->{ Recordset }->Close();
  $oAdoDG = undef;
  $oAdoDC = undef;
}
```

will give you a flexible 'display/edit every recordset from every database accessible by ADO' type of data grid:

[image: ADO Grid]

at no costs. A person familiar with HTML (but not Tk or Wx) and ADO/Access/Excel (but not DBI) could build a nice Database GUI easily/effiently. The precondition (i.e. drawback) is: Even the deployment computers need to have the "Microsoft DataGrid Control 6.0 (OLEDB)" (there are a plain tabular, a hierarchical, and a flexible hierarchical grid control too; maybe more modern controls can be used also) installed in a development/design-time enabled mode.

Comment: I'll check all the answers real soon before accepting the best answer

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using:

- [Wx](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Wx-0.9909/Wx.pm) for the user interface (provides a more modern/native look than Tk; see also the main site [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/))
- [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-SQLite/) for local database storage
- [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) - submitting forms

Since you're using Windows, your best bet would be to install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) which includes SQLite and Mechanize.  Installing Wx or Tk is an extra step, but you should be able to find tutorials on the web from others who have done so.  You may also want to look at [Padre, the Perl IDE](http://padre.perlide.org/) which is a Perl editor / development environment (it also happens to use Wx).